# Is there a possibility to make accounts for mobile app on Firebase and let users log in with the preset credentials?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am making a mobile app. I wanted to use Firebase for authentification. Most of the users doesn't need to login, but there will be a staff group and there will be a login option for them. I want to preset accounts and let users log in to it, but I just don't know how can I achieve this. I thought about a Firebase database, but this NoSQL is simply catastrofic, I don't think it is usable for that purpose. Anyone can help with it?

Or anyone just knows some nice option where I can host for free a normal SQL database and make the authentification with it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, it seems good, I don't really thought that it is possible to create this with simple Firebase Auth but it will make things a lot more easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup accounts for people using the Auth dashboard in Firebase. It allows for you to setup credentials beforehand and fulfills your need to only provide user accounts to people. Then you just need to configure your project to use your Firebase project settings and setup a route using the Firebase Auth API to create a login page.

Auth API Reference
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth

[image: Firebase dashboard auth]